# Error says "Missing right parenthesis" in my SQL statement... but it's not! Help?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Here's my statement from my C# program:

(edit by gbn, formatted for clarity so not *all* on one line)

```
DbCommand.CommandText =
             @"SELECT 
      HIST.MBRSEP, HIST.LOCATION, HIST.BILLTYPE, HIST.BILLMOYR, LOCINFO.CYCLE, 
      LOCINFO.DIST, LOCINFO.LOCATION
    FROM 
      (CAV_MBRHISTDEL AS HIST INNER JOIN CAV_LOCINFODETL AS LOCINFO ON HIST.LOCATION = LOCINFO.LOCATION)
    WHERE
       LOCINFO.CYCLE = @CYCLE AND 
       LOCINFO.DIST = @DISTRICT AND 
       HIST.BILLTYPE = '09' AND 
       HIST.BILLMOYR <> '9999'";
```

Here's the error message:

> ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

There's only 2 parenthesis in my SQL statement, a right one and a left one.  I'm not sure what the error is telling me.  Any advice?

EDIT:  Here is how the parameters are defined:

```
        string cycle = cbCycle.Text;
        string district = cbDistrict.Text.Substring(0,2);
```

And here is where I add them to the DbCommand:

```
        DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CYCLE", cycle);
        DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DISTRICT", district);
```

Here's my complete code that triggers when someone clicks the 'Go' button on my form:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get parameters
        string cycle = cbCycle.Text;
        string district = cbDistrict.Text.Substring(0,2);

        //create a connection to the database
        OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=UPN2;uid=xxx;pwd=xxxx");
        DbConnection.Open();

        //create a command to extract the required data and
        //assign it to the connection string
        OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
        DbCommand.CommandText =
             @"SELECT HIST.MBRSEP, HIST.LOCATION, HIST.BILLTYPE, HIST.BILLMOYR, LOCINFO.CYCLE, LOCINFO.DIST, LOCINFO.LOCATION FROM CAV_MBRHISTDEL AS HIST INNER JOIN CAV_LOCINFODETL AS LOCINFO ON HIST.LOCATION = LOCINFO.LOCATION WHERE LOCINFO.CYCLE = @CYCLE AND LOCINFO.DIST = @DISTRICT AND HIST.BILLTYPE = '09' AND HIST.BILLMOYR <> '9999'; ";

        DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CYCLE", cycle);
        DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DISTRICT", district);

        //Create a DataAdapter to run the command and fill the datatable
        OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = DbCommand;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);


        tbOutput.Text = PrintDataTable(dt);

        DbCommand.Dispose();
        DbConnection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you set the parameters please? And what datatypes are they

Comment: Often when you get this sort of error, it means that the query compiler *expected* a closing parenthesis at a particular point, and something else was found instead. It may not mean that there is *no* right parenthesis (especially in this case where there certainly is). The query compiler just hasn't got there yet.

Comment: Why do you even need them there? It's just a join.

Comment: I would suggest removing your parentheses and seeing how it runs. I'm not sure about Oracle, but in most T-SQL DBMSs it's going to want some sort of alias after the parens for the resulting row-set.

Comment: gnb, I made an edit to my original post and added the information you were wanting to see.  Thanks!

Comment: I actually removed the parenthesis,and got an error message saying ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: @Kevin, What are the actual values of `cbCycle.Text` and `cbDistrict.Text.Substring(0,2)`?

Comment: In debug, the actual values are '04' and '14', for cbCycle.Text and cbDistrict.Text, respectively.

Comment: If you hardcore the parameters?

Comment: I hardcoded the parameters and got the error message: "ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended." This is without any parenthesis in the SQL command and hardcoded values for the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem might be that you are using an oracle reserved word as a column name and as a param name - namely `CYCLE`...
doing so might result in strange and erratic behaviour of the DB!

see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Depending on your db provider you might want to use `:` instead of `@` for params.

Comment: Hmm.  I wonder if that could be part of the problem, the use of the reserved keyword 'cycle'?

Comment: Yes, this was the final piece that got everything working as it should.  I greatly appreciate your help, Yahia, and everyone else that pitched in to help out.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the parentheses that you have: you don't need them.

Comment: I actually removed the parenthesis,and got an error message saying ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Progress, then.  Try putting a ; at the end of the statement.  That's just a guess, though: I'm more of a sql server guy.

Comment: I tried that, and got the same message about not being properly ended: "ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".  So strange!

Comment: You also need to remove the "AS" for the table aliases.

Comment: @jonearles: I would post your comment as an answer, since it's different enough from Joel's suggestion, and I think it may in fact be the real problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `SELECT` from the inner query. Try this:

```
...
FROM 
    (SELECT CAV_MBRHISTDEL AS HIST -- Added SELECT
    INNER JOIN CAV_LOCINFODETL AS LOCINFO ON HIST.LOCATION = LOCINFO.LOCATION)
WHERE
...
```

You have:

```
FROM 
    (CAV_MBRHISTDEL ... -- Missing SELECT
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that could cause a problem!  I added the SELECT to the inner query and tried to run the program.  I got another error message, but at least it's different.  When I try to fill the datatable dt, it errors out and says ORA-00903: invalid table name.  Hmm.

Comment: Well, I double verified that my table names are correct, so I'm not sure why there error message is saying "invalid table name".

Comment: wtf? Why the downvote?? btw, you may need to give an alias to your inner select - try this: `...ON HIST.LOCATION = LOCINFO.LOCATION) X`

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted you.  Heh, I'm looking for all the help I can get!  I'll try giving an alias to the inner select and see what happens.  I appreciate your help!